# How to review code of previously created function in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

i am new to AWS.
I need to create a Lambda function in AWS, but before it i need to review some code of previously created functions. But when i want to review code of function there's a message

```
The deployment package of your Lambda function "tes-GetInfo" is too large to enable inline code editing. However, you can still invoke your function.
```

Does anyone know is it possible to some how review it in AWS.
I was looking a lot but still haven't found any ways to do it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download your function code by exporting it, assuming your function was developed in some interpreted language like JavaScript/Python.

This can be done by doing an export to the function:

1. Go to your function and in the `Actions` dropdown select `Export function`:
   [image]
2. Chose `Download deployment package`.

[image]

This will download the deployed function locally and you will be able to investigate your code.

Comment: Thank you so much.
This worked and very helped me.